# Date time formats in PHP

Tags: php, date, time, date-format, time-format

I'm using the GoTo Webinar API and it expects a date format as shown below in the start time and end time elements of the array:

```
$params = [
    'subject' => 'Test 34',
    'description' => 'Test test test lalala',
    'times' => [[
        'startTime' => '2016-02-22T23:00:00Z',
        'endTime' => '2016-02-23T00:00:00Z'
    ]],
    'timeZone' => 'GMT'
];
```

Could somebody explain to me what the relevance of the T/Z means eitherside of the time part? Does this just mean apply the TimeZone element of GMT which is also passed in below?

If so, can I/how do I use the PHP date() function to format this: "2016-01-16 07:00:00" into the above format?

Comment: `T` is a separator between the date and time parts; `Z` is a timezone (Zulu time, aka GMT, UST or UTC) - See [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Cool, makes sense. So.. in PHP, can I add these to my string using a specific date/time format? Or I do I need to fudge something by concatenating date with "T" then time and finally "Z". The GoTo Webinar API returns an error if they are missing...

Comment: PHP can add these to your date if you format the date using the `c` format code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The data standard used.

They follow the **ISO 8601** standard. You can find more details about this standard at eg. [**the Wikipedia article on ISO 8601**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

---

#### About the meaning of the T :

> A single point in time can be represented by concatenating a complete
> date expression, the letter T as a delimiter, and a valid time
> expression. For example, "2007-04-05T14:30".

#### About the meaning of the Z :

> If the time is in UTC, add a Z directly after the time without a
> space. Z is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset. "09:30 UTC"
> is therefore represented as "09:30Z" or "0930Z". "14:45:15 UTC" would
> be "14:45:15Z" or "144515Z".

#### How to format a date according to the **ISO 8601** standard in PHP :

```
$datetime = new DateTime('2016-01-25 23:46:46');
$datetime->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The value Z itself only indicates a standard UTC Time (it means Zulu Time). It is used according the ISO 8601. So you can use something like `date(DateTime::ISO8601)`, and it should produce the output that you wants.